# How can I create a glyph bitmap for alphabet

Tags: java, javascript, glyph

I am looking for a way which allows me to create glyph bitmap for alphabet.
For example, I create the following for the letter '0', but i am wondering if there is a simpler way for me to create glyph bitmap for alphabet 'a-z' and 'A-Z'?

```
        { 1, 1, 1, 1 },
        { 1, 0, 0, 1 },
        { 1, 0, 0, 1 },
        { 1, 0, 0, 1 },
        { 1, 0, 0, 1 },
        { 1, 0, 0, 1 },
        { 1, 1, 1, 1 },
```

Thank you.

Comment: Nested arrays, and human-readable.. I think you've got it.

Answer (score 2):

[`java.awt.font.GlyphVector`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/font/GlyphVector.html) is a good alternative, as seen [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/Paints.htm).

Addendum: Once a glyph's outline has been rendered in a [`BufferedImage`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html), the corresponding [`WritableRaster`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/WritableRaster.html) becomes accessible.